# Does anyone have experience with a sph0645(i2s microphone) and esp32-s2?

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, i2s

I am trying with ESP32-S2 WROOM (full name: LilyGO TTGO T8 ESP32-S2 WROOM) to read the input from an i2s microphone(sph0645), and all I get is either silence or a noise (if the assigned pin is not in the microphone fits) so the connection must be correct, I think. I get 1 error message namely **E (10715) AUDIO_ELEMENT: [wav] Element already stopped**. This error message is nowhere to be found on the espressif forum so I have become a bit hopeless: P also good to know that this is my first post on this topic. So if you know a little more about how to make these two components (i2s microphone and esp32-s2) work, feel free!

To complete the story, this is the complete log.

```
    (64) boot: ESP-IDF v4.2-dirty 2nd stage bootloader
I (64) boot: compile time 15:26:45
I (64) boot: chip revision: 0
I (66) boot.esp32s2: SPI Speed : 80MHz
I (71) boot.esp32s2: SPI Mode : DIO
I (76) boot.esp32s2: SPI Flash Size : 4MB
I (81) boot: Enabling RNG early entropy source...
I (86) boot: Partition Table:
I (90) boot: ## Label Usage Type ST Offset Length
I (97) boot: 0 nvs WiFi data 01 02 00009000 00006000
I (104) boot: 1 phy_init RF data 01 01 0000f000 00001000
I (112) boot: 2 factory factory app 00 00 00010000 00100000
I (119) boot: End of partition table
I (124) esp_image: segment 0: paddr=0x00010020 vaddr=0x3f000020 size=0x0dafc ( 56060) map
I (144) esp_image: segment 1: paddr=0x0001db24 vaddr=0x3ffbf260 size=0x01f70 ( 8048) load
I (147) esp_image: segment 2: paddr=0x0001fa9c vaddr=0x40024000 size=0x00404 ( 1028) load
0x40024000: _WindowOverflow4 at C:/Users/kraan/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/xtensa/xtensa_vectors.S:1730I (153) esp_image: segment 3: paddr=0x0001fea8 vaddr=0x40024404 size=0x00170 ( 368) load
I (162) esp_image: segment 4: paddr=0x00020020 vaddr=0x40080020 size=0x2a02c (172076) map
0x40080020: _stext at ??:?I (206) esp_image: segment 5: paddr=0x0004a054 vaddr=0x40024574 size=0x0ace4 ( 44260) load
I (225) boot: Loaded app from partition at offset 0x10000
I (225) boot: Disabling RNG early entropy source...
I (225) cache: Instruction cache : size 8KB, 4Ways, cache line size 32Byte
I (233) cpu_start: Pro cpu up.
I (236) cpu_start: Application information:
I (241) cpu_start: Project name: record_wav
I (246) cpu_start: App version: 1
I (251) cpu_start: Compile time: Mar 4 2021 15:26:18
I (257) cpu_start: ELF file SHA256: f689f9b5ef13ab60...
I (263) cpu_start: ESP-IDF: v4.2-dirty
I (268) cpu_start: Single core mode
D (272) memory_layout: Checking 3 reserved memory ranges:
D (278) memory_layout: Reserved memory range 0x3ffb4000 - 0x3ffbf258
D (284) memory_layout: Reserved memory range 0x3ffbf260 - 0x3ffc1a20
D (291) memory_layout: Reserved memory range 0x3ffffa10 - 0x40000000
D (297) memory_layout: Building list of available memory regions:
D (303) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffc1a20 - 0x3ffc4000
D (310) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffc4000 - 0x3ffc8000
D (316) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffc8000 - 0x3ffcc000
D (323) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffcc000 - 0x3ffd0000
D (330) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffd0000 - 0x3ffd4000
D (336) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffd4000 - 0x3ffd8000
D (343) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffd8000 - 0x3ffdc000
D (349) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffdc000 - 0x3ffe0000
D (356) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffe0000 - 0x3ffe4000
D (363) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffe4000 - 0x3ffe8000
D (369) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffe8000 - 0x3ffec000
D (376) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3ffec000 - 0x3fff0000
D (382) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3fff0000 - 0x3fff4000
D (389) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3fff4000 - 0x3fff8000
D (396) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3fff8000 - 0x3fffc000
D (402) memory_layout: Available memory region 0x3fffc000 - 0x3ffffa10
I (409) heap_init: Initializing. RAM available for dynamic allocation:
D (416) heap_init: New heap initialised at 0x3ffc1a20
I (421) heap_init: At 3FFC1A20 len 0003A5E0 (233 KiB): DRAM
I (427) heap_init: At 3FFFC000 len 00003A10 (14 KiB): DRAM
I (433) cpu_start: Pro cpu start user code
D (491) clk: RTC_SLOW_CLK calibration value: 5765894
D (497) intr_alloc: Connected src 49 to int 2 (cpu 0)
D (497) intr_alloc: Connected src 73 to int 10 (cpu 0)
D (497) intr_alloc: Connected src 28 to int 3 (cpu 0)
D (503) FLASH_HAL: extra_dummy: 0
D (506) spi_flash: trying chip: issi
D (510) spi_flash: trying chip: gd
D (513) spi_flash: trying chip: mxic
D (517) spi_flash: trying chip: generic
I (521) spi_flash: detected chip: generic
I (526) spi_flash: flash io: dio
I (530) cpu_start: Starting scheduler on PRO CPU.
D (535) heap_init: New heap initialised at 0x3fffc000
D (535) intr_alloc: Connected src 17 to int 9 (cpu 0)
I (545) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ 1 ] Mount sdcard
D (545) intr_alloc: Connected src 23 to int 12 (cpu 0)
D (555) intr_alloc: Connected src 34 to int 13 (cpu 0)
I (605) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ 2 ] Start codec chip
I (605) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [3.0] Create audio pipeline for recording
I (605) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [3.1] Create fatfs stream to write data to sdcard
I (615) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [3.2] Create i2s stream to read audio data from codec chip
D (625) intr_alloc: Connected src 35 to int 19 (cpu 0)
I (635) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [3.3] Create wav encoder to encode wav format
I (635) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [3.4] Register all elements to audio pipeline
I (645) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [3.5] Link it together [codec_chip]-->i2s_stream-->wav_encoder-->fatfs_stream-->[sdcard]
I (655) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [3.6] Set up uri (file as fatfs_stream, wav as wav encoder)
I (665) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ 4 ] Set up event listener
I (665) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [4.1] Listening event from pipeline
I (675) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [4.2] Listening event from peripherals
I (685) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ 5 ] Start audio_pipeline
I (695) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ 6 ] Listen for all pipeline events, record for 10 Seconds
I (1715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 1
I (2715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 2
I (3715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 3
I (4715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 4
I (5715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 5
I (6715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 6
I (7715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 7
I (8715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 8
I (9715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 9
I (10715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ * ] Recording ... 10
I (10715) REC_WAV_SDCARD: [ 7 ] Stop audio_pipeline
W (10715) AUDIO_ELEMENT: IN-[wav] AEL_IO_ABORT
E (10715) AUDIO_ELEMENT: [wav] Element already stopped
W (10725) AUDIO_ELEMENT: IN-[file] AEL_IO_ABORT
W (10735) AUDIO_PIPELINE: There are no listener registered
W (10735) AUDIO_ELEMENT: [file] Element has not create when AUDIO_ELEMENT_TERMINATE
W (10745) AUDIO_ELEMENT: [i2s] Element has not create when AUDIO_ELEMENT_TERMINATE
W (10755) AUDIO_ELEMENT: [wav] Element has not create when AUDIO_ELEMENT_TERMINATE
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're using?